# Is this first order differential equation solvable for p?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is : $xp^2 −2yp + ax = 0$

It is given as an example under "solvable for $y$" in my book.
Shouldn't this also be solvable for $p$, since it can be factorised and is a *quadratic in $p$*?
I tried to use the quadratic formula but my answer is wrong.
*Is there something about the equation I'm missing?*

Comment: In your book, I believe that p is in fact a parameter not a variable. So you cannot really "solve for p" since it doesn't look like p lies inside the solution vector space of the ode.

Comment: @JoelBiffin Sorry! I should have mentioned, p represents dy/dx.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$p^2-2\frac{y}{x}p+a=0$$

Let $y=ux$, then $p=u+x\frac {du}{dx}$. Substituting gives $$x^2(\frac{du}{dx})^2=u^2-a$$.

Take the square root and you now have a separable variable equation which can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes solving with respect to $p$ is possible and we obtain

$$p=\frac{2y\pm\sqrt{4y^2-4ax^2}}{2x}=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-ax^2}}{x}$$

but all also depends form the context of your specific problem, from what $p$ represents, form what you are requested to find.

Comment: thank you! I am not sure what you mean by context?  p represents the derivative of y wrt x (and the equation is just one of many in an exercise for differential equations solvable for y)

Comment: @ali Therefore solve for $p$ by quadratic equation is not useful!

Comment: Why? (i finally solved my answer further and it did match, but i really do want to know why one would rather solve for y in such a situation)

Comment: @ali Because it is and ODE and we need to find the function $y(x)$. The variable $p=y'(x)$  not another unkown since it is the derivative of the same function $y(x)$.